# Cannot pack fork of azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet into nuget package

Tags: azure, nuget, nuget-package

I made a fork of the library `azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet` and tried to pack it into a nuget package but failed.

I run the following command on the Developer Command Prompt to try to pack my fork into a nuget package.

```
nuget Pack src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.csproj
```

And this is the error I get when I run this command:

```
Unable to find 'bin\Debug\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\bin\Debug\'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

But the project is build succesfull and contains the following folder in the debug folder:
[image: Folder image]

- My fork [github page](https://github.com/kevingoos/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet)
- The page where the original azure project is stored: [Github azure](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet)
- Link to issue I created on the github page: [Issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/863)